# Markdown - Embedding images with a relative path

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I searched quiet a lot, but could not find a solution that works. It seems it is not possible to link local images with a relativ path in markdown.
I am building a documentation with doxygen, using markdown. I am working with Windows.

Example:

```
![titlepic](.\titlepic.jpg)
```

If I use the absolute path like

```
![ROMoCapSys](C:\titlepic.jpg)
```

Everthing works fine. But of course this solution is not portable.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correctly set up `IMAGE_PATH` see: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_image_path

and:
http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdimage